# Save cache folder on seperate partition with superfast filesystem?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, cache

I'm reading about disks, partitions, filesystems, recovery. I have a lack of knowledge about them.

To learn things I mentally model abstract situations.

So, imagine... I have the ubuntu server with one partition. I have the website and save cache to some directory.

Is it worth to have another partition, install some specific fast filesystem (maybe without journaling) and save cache there? Will I have any benefits (even insignificant improvements are appropriate for this situation)?

Comment: for a web server's cache, probably the best thing you can do is use a `tmpfs`, tune the mount options and setup a cron job for persistence to disk.

Comment: I know about that filesystem, but all files will be located in RAM. And I'm interested to save them on disk.